# Render a single UIImage and rotation has to be applied

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, drawing, core-graphics, image-rotation

I have rendered few UIImage objects using CGContextDrawImage. But when i apply rotation to the image, it is not applied and the view disappears. 
`code here`

-(void )renderImage: (ItemView *)array
{

```
 NSArray *selectedImages =  self.slideView.selectedView.subviews;

CGSize combinedSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < [selectedImages count]; ++i) {
    CGSize sourceSize = [selectedImages[i] size];
    NSLog(@"sdfsd %f %f ", sourceSize.width, sourceSize.height);
    combinedSize.width = MAX(combinedSize.width, sourceSize.width);
    combinedSize.height += sourceSize.height;
}



   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
{


    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, 768);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1,-1);




    for (int i = 0; i < [selectedImages count]; ++i) {
        UIImageView *imageview = selectedImages[i];
        UIImage *sourceImage = imageview.image;


        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        float radians1 = atan2(imageview.transform.a, imageview.transform.b);




       CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[imageview valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

        printf("\n radians %f",radians1);
        printf("\n angle %f",angle);

        CGContextRotateCTM(context, radians(angle));
        CGContextDrawImage(context, imageview.frame, imageview.image.CGImage);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        //CGContextDrawImage(context, imageview.frame, imageview.image);

    }

}
UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(combinedImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

}

Thanks,

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "image above should be considered as one" means, give more info

Comment: huh? what's the question?

Comment: I think he is suggesting the images above and below should pile up with the image in front visible.

Comment: I have a few UIImage objects which I want to compose into a single UIImage and draw the UIImage objects in there using something like CGContextDrawImage .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have an array of source images:

```
NSArray *sourceImages = ...;
// each element of sourceImages is a UIImage
```

Now you want to take the first `count` images from the array and concatenate them vertically into a new image.  Start by figuring out the size of the combined image:

```
CGSize combinedSize = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    CGSize sourceSize = [sourceImages[i] size];
    combinedSize.width = MAX(combinedSize.width, sourceSize.width);
    combinedSize.height += sourceSize.height;
}
```

Next, create a graphics context of that size:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(combinedSize, NO, 0); {
```

Now draw each component image into the graphics context at the appropriate position:

```
    CGFloat y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        UIImage *sourceImage = sourceImages[i];
        [sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, y)];
        y += sourceImage.size.height;
    }
```

Finally, create the combined image from the context and dispose of the context:

```
}
UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Read [*Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS* - Drawing and Creating Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/HandlingImages/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH13-SW1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. It works .But if i touch the another image in the array, the entire image context should be redrawn .Any help ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I cracked the answer . @ rob mayoff : Thanks much who helped me out.

```
 code here
```

//code to render group of images excluding the image which has been selected in a particular view

-(void )renderImage: (ItemView *)selectedItem
{

```
NSArray *selectedImages =  self.slideView.selectedView.subviews;
int selectedItemIndex = [selectedImages indexOfObject:selectedItem];
if(selectedItem.image==nil){
    [selectedItem loadImageFromFile];
}


// first set
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.slideView.selectedView.frame.size, NO, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < selectedItemIndex; ++i) {

    if([selectedImages[i] isKindOfClass:[ItemView class]]){

        ItemView *imageview = (ItemView *)selectedImages[i];
        CGAffineTransform transform = imageview.transform;
        imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageview.filename];
        UIImageView *renderImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; //[imageview copy];
        renderImageView.frame = imageview.frame;
        renderImageView.bounds = imageview.bounds;
        imageview.transform = transform;
        renderImageView.transform = transform;
        renderImageView.center = CGPointMake(imageview.frame.size.width/2,imageview.frame.size.height/2);
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:renderImageView.frame];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [view addSubview:renderImageView];
        [renderImageView release];
        [image release];
        imageview.image = nil;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageview.frame.size);
        CGContextRef context1 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [view.layer renderInContext:context1];
        UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [view release];

        [result drawAtPoint:imageview.frame.origin];
    }

}
UIImage *combinedImage1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(combinedImage1, nil, nil, nil);


if (groupBgImage1) {
    [groupBgImage1 removeFromSuperview];
    [groupBgImage1 release];
    groupBgImage1 = nil;
}
groupBgImage1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:combinedImage1];
[self.slideView.selectedView insertSubview:groupBgImage1 belowSubview:selectedItem ];

// second set
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.slideView.selectedView.frame.size, NO, 0);
for (int i = selectedItemIndex+1; i < [selectedImages count]; ++i) {


    if([selectedImages[i] isKindOfClass:[ItemView class]]){
        ItemView *imageview = (ItemView *)selectedImages[i];
        CGAffineTransform transform = imageview.transform;
        imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageview.filename];
        UIImageView *renderImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; //[imageview copy];
        renderImageView.frame = imageview.frame;
        renderImageView.bounds = imageview.bounds;
        imageview.transform = transform;
        renderImageView.transform = transform;
        renderImageView.center = CGPointMake(imageview.frame.size.width/2,imageview.frame.size.height/2);
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:renderImageView.frame];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [view addSubview:renderImageView];

        [renderImageView release];
        [image release];
        imageview.image = nil;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageview.frame.size);
        CGContextRef context1 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [view.layer renderInContext:context1];
        UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [view release];

        [result drawAtPoint:imageview.frame.origin];
    }

}
UIImage *combinedImage2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(combinedImage2, nil, nil, nil);



if (groupBgImage2) {
    [groupBgImage2 removeFromSuperview];
    [groupBgImage2 release];
    groupBgImage2 = nil;
}
groupBgImage2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:combinedImage2];
[self.slideView.selectedView insertSubview:groupBgImage2 aboveSubview:selectedItem ];
```

}